# Sharing local image to Instagram in React Native (Android)

Tags: android, react-native, instagram

At the moment I can't find any modules for React Native that support local image sharing to Instagram. Even the most comprehensive sharing module which is [react-native-share](https://github.com/EstebanFuentealba/react-native-share) doesn't support Instagram. There are couple of packages for iOS but nothing for Android.

I'm looking for example custom implementations or module suggestions that I might have missed.

Answer (score 1):

You can only post using Instagram's app. You can however use webhooks to open an image from your app in Instagram app, and then user will have to continue and do the actual posting in Instagram app. You have to write your own react native module, Check this documentation: https://www.instagram.com/developer/mobile-sharing/